# Lower bound on expectation of concave function

Tags: expected-value, probability-inequalities, bounds, convex, concavity

Let $X$ be a random variable, and let $f$ be a concave function.

Are there any known *lower bounds* for (or methods of lower bounding) $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$?

Jensen's inequality only gives an upper bound on the above.

Comment: An obvious lower bound is $\text{E}[f(X)]\geqslant \inf_{x\in S} f(x)$ where $S$ is the support of the random variable  $X$.

Comment: That bound given by @Stijn is the best possible in general: since there is no assumption connecting $X$ to $f$, $X$ could have all its probability concentrated in an interval $[\inf f, \inf f+\epsilon)$ for arbitrarily small positive $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is helpful, but for any function $f$ set  $Z \equiv f(X)$. Then by Jensen's Inequality

$$E(Z^2) > [E(Z)]^2 \implies \sqrt {E(Z^2)} > \big |E(Z)\big |$$

$$\implies -\sqrt {E(Z^2)} < E(Z) < \sqrt {E(Z^2)} $$

$$ \implies -\sqrt {E([f(X)]^2)} < E[f(X)] < \sqrt {E([f(X)]^2)} $$

Answer (score 0):

A lower bound for E[f(X)]? (for a concave function f)
is any **upper** bound on the expectation E[f(X)] of a **convex** function f,
e.g., see Edmundson-Madansky type inequalities:
1 - Edmundson, H.P. (1956): Bounds on the expectation of a convex function of a random variable. Technical report, The Rand Corporation Paper 982, Santa Monica, California;
and, 2 - Madansky, A. (1959): Bounds on the expectation of a convex function of a multivariate random variable. Ann. Math. Stat. 30, 743–746;
or, Dula's type bounds:
3 - Dul´a, J.H. (1992): An upper bound on the expectation of simplicial functions of multivariate random variables. Math. Program. 55, 69–80