# Tight upper bound on the expectation of a concave function

Tags: expected-value, probability-inequalities, bounds

N is a random variable whose sample space is [0,$\infty$). I have an expression in terms of the expectation of this variable and I want to find a tight upper bound on the whole expression. The expression is as below:

$1-\gamma E[\frac{(N+1)}{(1+b*N+\gamma *N+b+\gamma)}]$ where $\gamma >0$ and $b>0$

I don't know the distribution of N but assuming that I know the $E[N]$, can a tight bound be established on the above expression? If so, can you please refer me to theorems/inequalities that would help me find it?
I looked at [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) but it provides a lower bound since the expression over which the expectation is being taken is concave.

(This expression is actually a bound on the probability mass for a subset of the sample space but I don't know the distribution.)

Comment: You can simplify the problem considerably by re-expressing it in terms of the random variable $X=1+(b+\gamma)(1+N),$ thereby reducing it to bounding $E[1/X]$ given $E[X]$ and a lower bound on the support of $X.$

Comment: @whuber, thank you for the reply. Wouldn't [1/X] become convex now and applying Jensen's give a lower bound again for the whole expression? I think the expression would become $1−p+p*E[1/X]$ where X is as defined by you and $p=\frac{\gamma}{b+\gamma}$

Comment: you may see this one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248142/lower-bound-on-expectation-of-concave-function

Comment: this link might help:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248142/lower-bound-on-expectation-of-concave-function